# Security on single application/database server with PostgreSQL and Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, tomcat, centos

(This isn't a question about whether it's better to use separate servers or a single server for  application and database)

My situation is that I've chosen to use a single server configuration with PostgreSQL as the database, and two Java applications (with built in security) running on Tomcat (one for internal office work, and another for a client portal).

**My question is: What are the most important things for me to do to ensure that security is as best as it can be under this situation?**

*For example, should I run a separate Tomcat instance for each application, on separate ports and block anonymous access to the internal application port?*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first recommend that you build two separate schemas in your RDBMS. This will provide you two primary benefits. 1 will be a separate user for the security concerns. The second is that if you ever decide to separate it you can.

I would consider using database pools with encrypted passwords as well to further secure your security information.

Consider using Apache rules (assuming limited budget) with tomcat forwarding to restrict URL access by IP, that way your client portal is open to the outside while your internal is only available inside the network.

Reduce the use of shared jars, in fact the more you can pack into your wars the better so you don't ever get bit by some static reference you don't control that can break something... me being overly paranoid I am sure.

My $0.02.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Here are my comments: (1) The client portal needs access to some of the same data as the internal app, so I am not planning on going with 2 schemas, but definitely two users with different sets of privileges. (2) Do you mean db connection pools, for example using JNDI? If so, then I'm not sure how this helps security-wise, though it should in terms of server stability (or so I've read). (3) I'll look into that. (4) I don't believe I'm using shared jars unless Tomcat does that automatically, but I'll look into that. I'll wait a few days before I accept answers.